# Is it possible to parsing Html inside jQuery .append with php condition?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to update user wall comment yet when another user submit his comment. Here my user submitting a comment by jQuery with php. Comment submit is working well. My problem is in update wall of others user page yet.

So for update, as a simple way, I used below code to update it on all user wall page yet.

But I used many php condition to post a success comment.

Here is my php echo'' below which post a comment after success.

```
echo'<div class="case postcom'.$id.'"><div class="comment">
    <div class="cdomment_cheder">
    <div class="avatarcnt">
    <img alt="" src="uploadprofile/'.$u_imgurl.'"/></div><div class="newkochi">';
    if ($url=="") {
    echo'<p class="name">'.$username.' Says:</p>'; }
    else  echo'<p class="name"><a href="'.$url.'" title="'.$username.'">'.$username.'</a> Says:</p>';
    echo'<span class="cdomment_time">'.$date.'</span>
    <div class="cdomment_text">';
    if ($description=="") {echo '';}
    else echo''.nl2br(smileys($description)).'<br>';
    if ($img=="") {echo '';}
    else echo'<br><img src="comimage/'.$img.'" />';
    echo '</div>';

    //delete
    include_once("session.php");
    if($_SESSION['username'] == "admin" or $_SESSION['username'] == trim($_GET['user'])){
    echo'<div class="delete_box"><a href="javascript: void(0)" id="delc'.$id.'" class="delete">Delete</a></div>';
    }
    //Likes
    echo'<div class="likePanel"><span id="like-panel-'.$id.'">';

    if($like_ip_num > 0){       
    echo'<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="post_id'.$id.'" class="Unlike">Unlike</a>';
        } else {
            echo'<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="post_id'.$id.'" class="LikeThis">Like</a>';
        }           
        echo'</span><span class="bubble">           
            <span id="like-stats-'.$id.'"> '.$likes.' </span> liked </span></div></div></div>'; 
    echo'</div>';
```

So as per above code I want to append(In case of update wall) it by jQuery and I was tried as below, but I cannot under stand how to apply my php `if` condition also my delete and like button.

```
$(".content").append("<div class='"+ type +"'><div class='comment'>
<div class='cdomment_cheder'><div class='avatarcnt'><img alt=''   src='uploadprofile/"+ msg.u_imgurl +"'/></div>
<div class='newkochi'><p class='name'><a href='"+ msg.url +"' title='"+ msg.username +"'>"+ msg.username +"</a> Says:</p><span class='cdomment_time'>"+ msg.date +"</span>
<div class='cdomment_text'>"+ msg.description +"<br><br><img src='comimage/"+ msg.img +"' /></div>
</div></div></div></div>");
```

Here is my full update post code for your further require

jQuery:

```
function addmsg(type, msg){
    $(".content").append("<div class='"+ type +"'><div class='comment'><div class='cdomment_cheder'><div class='avatarcnt'><img alt='' src='uploadprofile/"+ msg.u_imgurl +"'/></div><div class='newkochi'><p class='name'><a href='"+ msg.url +"' title='"+ msg.username +"'>"+ msg.username +"</a> Says:</p><span class='cdomment_time'>"+ msg.date +"</span><div class='cdomment_text'>"+ msg.description +"<br><br><img src='comimage/"+ msg.img +"' /></div></div></div></div></div>");
}

function waitForMsg(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/server.php",
        cache: false,
        timeout:15000, 
        success: function(data){ 
            addmsg("case", data);
            setTimeout(
                waitForMsg, 
                15000 
            );
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            setTimeout(
                waitForMsg, 
                15000); 
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    waitForMsg(); 
});
```

server.php

```
include("../db.php");
global $dbh;
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
while (true) {
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/...');
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-15 second'));
$results = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE qazi_id='1012' AND date >= '$datetime' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
$rows =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

$row[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $rows);
$data = array();

$data['id'] = $rows['id']; /* I want use this id to display once*/
$data['qazi_id'] = $rows['qazi_id'];
$data['likes'] = $rows['likes'];
$data['username'] = $rows['username'];
$data['img'] = $rows['img'];
$data['description'] = $rows['description'];
$data['url'] = $rows['url'];
$data['parent_id'] = $rows['parent_id'];
$data['date'] = $rows['date'];
//has data

if (!empty($data)) {
    echo json_encode($data);
    flush();
    exit(0);
}
sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: you want to add echo html to add jquery .append

Comment: Yes sir. total php echo want to add jquery .append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. in server.php

```
<?php
 if($_SESSION['username'] == "admin" or $_SESSION['username'] == trim($_GET['user'])){
    $html .='<div class="delete_box"><a href="javascript: void(0)" id="delc'.$id.'" class="delete">Delete</a></div>';
    }
    //Likes
    $html .='<div class="likePanel"><span id="like-panel-'.$id.'">';

    if($like_ip_num > 0){       
     $html .='<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="post_id'.$id.'" class="Unlike">Unlike</a>';
        } else {
            $html .='<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="post_id'.$id.'" class="LikeThis">Like</a>';
        }           
        $html .='</span><span class="bubble">           
            <span id="like-stats-'.$id.'"> '.$likes.' </span> liked </span></div></div></div></div>'; 
    ?>

$data['html'] = $html;
```

Add `"+ msg.html +"` where you want add buttons.

Your script will be like as:

```
<script>
$(".content").append("<div class='"+ type +"'><div class='comment'><div class='cdomment_cheder'><div class='avatarcnt'><img alt='' src='uploadprofile/"+ msg.u_imgurl +"'/></div><div class='newkochi'><p class='name'><a href='"+ msg.url +"' title='"+ msg.username +"'>"+ msg.username +"</a> Says:</p><span class='cdomment_time'>"+ msg.date +"</span><div class='cdomment_text'>"+ msg.description +"<br><br><img src='comimage/"+ msg.img +"' /></div>"+ msg.html +"</div></div></div></div>");
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, Where I will place this php code ( server.php or JQ script's page).  If I add this line `<?php echo $html;?>` in .append, It's don't display any update.

Comment: Update your script that I modified, and its work well now. Thank u so much.